# Is there a way to know whether locationManager is active or stopped?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

In my app, I am developing a CoreLocation functionality module and I need to know whether `startUpdatingLocation` or `stopUpdatingLocation` have been called.
I know I could use a boolean variable, but I wonder if there is something more 'globally' useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to check the "running" status for the CLLocationManager. You could wrap CLLocationManager in a class (or subclass it) and have "running" state on this custom class.

Something like this perhaps:

Swift:

```
class MyLocationManager: CLLocationManager {
    var running: Bool

    override init() {
        running = false
        super.init()
    }

    override func startUpdatingLocation() {
        super.startUpdatingLocation()
        running = true
    }

    override func stopUpdatingLocation() {
        super.stopUpdatingLocation()
        running = false
    }

}
```

ObjC:

```
@interface MyLocationManager : CLLocationManager
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL running;
@end

@implementation MyLocationManager
- (void) startUpdatingLocation
{
    [super startUpdatingLocation];
    self.running = YES;
}

- (void) stopUpdatingLocation
{
    [super stopUpdatingLocation];
    self.running = NO;
}
@end
```

PS: This class is not thread safe, but you get the idea